# Check every value for each similar keys whether it meets the condition for each key in 2 dict - PYTHON

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I have these datas in 2 dictionaries.

```
dict1 = {"A":2, "B": 2, "C":2}
dict2 = {"A":2, "B":100, "C":100)
```

I check values for each keys whether values in dict1 is more than values in dict2.
Example:

```
if dict1["A"]>=dict2["A"]:
   print("There are enough A parts")
if dict1["B"]>=dict2["B"]:
   print("There are enough B parts")
```

Is there a way for me to check all values between the 2 dictionaries without having to do the above?
Here's how it is for better understanding:

```
dict1={}
dict2 = {"A":2, "B":100, "C":100}
productID= "ABBB" #productID
quantityInput = 100
quantityToMake = productID*quantityInput #results in ABBB x100 times

 *** PROGRAM RUNS through each letter and update how many A and Bs are there and updates dict1
```

I'm stuck here. The condition is, if I have enough of the parts ie A,B,C,D, as in the case above,
I have enough of "A" to make only 2 "ABBB".

If we have the dict2 values for each key as below:

```
dict2 = {"A":100, "B":2, "C":100}
```

I don't have enough B to make 1 "ABBB" since we need 3 "B" to make 1 "ABBB".

Your help is much appreciated. Quite new to python.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this `if dict1["A"]>=dict2["A"]:` comparison should be the other way round `if dict1["A"]<=dict2["A"]:` or `if dict2["A"]>=dict1["A"]:`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `dict2` has all the same keys as `dict1`, you can just loop through the keys of `dict1` and compare each value:

```
In [20]: dict1 = {"A":2, "B": 2, "C":2, "D":4}
    ...: dict2 = {"A":2, "B":100, "C":100, "D":2}

In [21]: for k, v in dict1.items():
    ...:     if v >= dict2[k]:
    ...:         print(f"There are enough {k} parts")
    ...:
There are enough A parts
There are enough D parts
```

You might also consider using `pandas` if you're essentially trying to deal with tabular data since it makes a lot of these sorts of comparisons and updates fairly easy:

```
In [22]: import pandas as pd

In [23]: df = pd.DataFrame([dict1, dict2]).T

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   0    1
A  2    2
B  2  100
C  2  100
D  4    2

In [25]: df.index[df[0].ge(df[1])]
Out[25]: Index(['A', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! There's another layer I need to ask about. If lets say I want to output the number of "ABBB"  I can make based on dict1 and dict2, how do I do that? Eg, based on my question above, I can make 2 Nos of "ABBB" given first scenario of dict2 and I cannot make any "ABBB" given second scenario of dict2.